# Kafka Streams aggregate over time per key- windows not closing if no more events seen for key

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am attempting to build a Kafka Streams application to reduce the volume of events by simply producing the latest event for each key over a period of time (e.g. 1 minute). I cannot guarantee that during a given window there will be more events for any key (keys are high cardinality and change over time).

What I am seeing is that the window only closes once an event is received that has a timestamp out with the window for the given key.

For example, if I have a window size of 1 minute, have the timestamp extractor configured to use the timestamp in the input messages, and feed in the following messages:

```
{"timestamp_ms":10000, "id": "1", "favorite_count": 1}
{"timestamp_ms":20000, "id": "1", "favorite_count": 2}
{"timestamp_ms":30000, "id": "1", "favorite_count": 3}
{"timestamp_ms":40000, "id": "1", "favorite_count": 4}
{"timestamp_ms":50000, "id": "1", "favorite_count": 5}
{"timestamp_ms":65000, "id": "2", "favorite_count": 1}
```

No aggregate is produced until I feed in a message with timestamp > 59,999 for ID 1.

The stream config is this:

```
KStream<String, Event> stream = kStreamBuilder.stream(inputTopic.name())
        .filter(this::isValid)
        .peek((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + ":" + v))
        .selectKey(Event::getId())
        .repartition()
        .groupByKey()
        .windowedBy(TimeWindows.ofSizeAndGrace(Duration.ofMinutes(1), Duration.ofMillis(10)))
        .reduce((Event a, Event b) -> {
                    Event newestEvent = a.timestamp_ms() > b.timestamp_ms() ? a : b;
                    return newestEvent;
                },
                Named.as("windowStoreDefault"),
                Materialized.with(Serdes.String(), jsonSerde))
        .suppress(Suppressed.untilWindowCloses(Suppressed.BufferConfig.unbounded()))
        .toStream()
        .filter((k, v) -> Objects.nonNull(v))
        .peek((k, v) -> System.out.println("Aggregate:" + k + ":" + v))
        .selectKey((k, v) -> v.getId())
        .to(outputTopic.name(), Produced.with(Serdes.String(), jsonSerde));
```

Is there any windowing I can use to make the message coming in for another ID close the window?

Comment: Turns out, what I was missing, is the windowing time advancement occurs per partition. In my POC I changed it to a single partition and that solved the issue. In production this will not actually be an issue as the high cardinality IDs will be distributed evenly over the partitions.